# Predict polynomial values

Tags: python, numpy

I have data forming a curve. I want to fit it to predict the following data:
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyTlw.png)

The green line is the real data. The red points are the samples I use to predict the rest of data. The blue line is the result of my prediction.

To do that, I use this:

```
fig = plt.figure('Line and predict')
plt.clf()
x = np.arange(0, len(peaks), 1)
plt.plot(x, peaks, 'r.')
real_peaks = np.flipud(np.array([372, 394, 418, 444, 474, 504, 538, 574, 614, 657, 705, 758, 817, 882, 955, 1039, 1133, 1241, 1365, 1509]))
peaks = np.flipud(np.array([504, 538, 574, 614, 657, 705, 758, 817, 882, 955, 1039, 1133, 1241, 1365, 1509]))
for i in range(6):
    print('peaks', peaks)
    pfit = self.__fit_polynome__(peaks)
    axis = np.linspace(0, len(peaks) + 1, 200)
    plt.xlabel('line')
    plt.ylabel('horizontal lines position')
    x = np.arange(0, len(peaks), 1)
    plt.plot(x_real_peaks, real_peaks, 'g',  axis, pfit(axis), 'b--')
    plt.draw()
    peaks = np. append(peaks, int(pfit(len(peaks))))


def __fit_polynome__(self, data):
        x = np.arange(0, len(data), 1)
        fit = np.polyfit(x, data, 4)
        pfit = np.poly1d(fit)
        return pfit
```

So I predict the next data and I add it to my samples to be able to predict the next one.
As you can see on the image, the result is not perfect. Is there another method to have better results?
I've tried UnivariateSpline or CubicSpline (scipy.interpolate) but it is worst.

Comment: A Savitzky-Golay filter maybe?

Comment: The data look like a decaying exponential, have you tried fitting an exponential instead of a polynomial?

Comment: I've tried with curve_fit and the result is also not good.